# Unwanted different parskip length around tabularx

Tags: xetex, tabularx, scrbook, vertical-spacing, parskip

I tried to use the tabularx environment to align my long thesis title at the colon like it is shown in the picture below. Between every entry I wish to have the vertical spacing of one parskip like it is used in normal text (example: spacing between university and department). Somehow, spacing looks in general pretty inconsistent if you look closely. I know parskip is a stretchable length but how can I achieve uniform vertical spacing especially around the tabluarx environment. Thanks!

Note: the text will be put into a framed environment, but I don't think this is the problem here.

[image]

MWE (scrbook class with compiled xelatex):

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    10pt,
    parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\onehalfspacing

\newlength{\defaulttabcolsep}
\setlength{\defaulttabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}
Author:~Author \hfill Type of the work: Thesis\\[\parskip]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
    Title:~ & Tabularx environment is used to align long titles at the colon Tabularx environment is used to align long titles at the colon\\[\parskip]
    Test & Test\\[\parskip]
\end{tabularx}
\setlength\tabcolsep{\defaulttabcolsep}
Date:~\today\\[\parskip]
University:~University

Department:~Department
\end{document}
```

Edit:

I now put the `linegoal` code into the `framed` environment. Unfortunately, it needs sometimes 6 or more iterations in my main document till compilation terminates and the `parbox` is not fully justified anymore, which probably indicates that the remaining line width is calculated not correctly.

[image]

Has anyone an idea, whether with the table approach or another?

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    10pt,
    parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{framed}

\onehalfspacing
\newlength{\defaulttabcolsep}
\setlength{\defaulttabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}
Author:~Author \hfill Type of the work: Thesis\\[\parskip]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
    Title:~ & Tabularx environment is used to align long titles at the colon Tabularx environment is used to align long titles at the colon%\\[\parskip]
\end{tabularx}\setlength\tabcolsep{\defaulttabcolsep}

Date:~\today%\\[\parskip]

University:~University

Department:~Department

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{oframed}
    Author:~Author \hfill Type of the work: Thesis\\[\parskip]
    Title:~\parbox[t][2\baselineskip]{\linegoal}{Tabularx environment is used to align long titles at the colon Tabularx environment is used to align long titles at the colon}\\[\parskip]
    Date:~\today\\[\parskip]
    University:~University of \LaTeX\\[\parskip]
    Department:~Department of Typesetting
\end{oframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Don't abuse tables for layout purposes. 2) have a look here and elsewher on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages?lang=de (It starts displaying title layouts, and shows latex-coding later.) // For "elsewhere" see e.g. here: https://ctan.org/topic/titlepage

Comment: in general just use a blank line (which is a paragraph so adds `\parskip`) not `\\[\parskip]` inside tabulars `\parskip` is 0pt anyway, so just use a blank lin after the tabularx

Comment: Why would you have some but not all the fields in the same tabularx environment? Why not either use one big tabularx or give each field its own? It's not that clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MS-SPO It is not the title page, it's a form in between the thesis.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I just insert an empty line below, the spacing is still smaller than in normal text and in case of the spacing above, if I remove the newline and add also an empty line, hfill doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @frabjous It's a Word template fixed by the university and therefore it has to be like this. But to clarify, if the title requires more than two lines it should be aligned at the colon. So the second row should start not at the far left below "Title:". Though, I'm open to other solutions without tables.

Comment: I just don't understand what's going on with the `Test & Test \\\\ `; why another row in the same tabularx as the title? Is there some *other* field that needs to be lined up with the title horizontally? The title itself is just going to be wrapped in the first row.

Comment: @frabjous Ok sorry, forgot to mention. This table row is just for checking how a parskip within a table looks and will be not part of the final layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, boy! The usual problems with `parskip=half`, where the `\parfillskip` is set to a nonzero natural width in an attempt to hide the problems `parskip` poses.

Well, I see no reason for `\linegoal`, since you could simply use `\linewidth` as in the other case. You get an overfull box by 10pt because of `\parfillskip`, but that's easy to cope with without `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    10pt,
    parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand{\longhang}[2]{%
  \par
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1: }%
  \hangindent=\dimen0 \hangafter=1
  \mbox{#1: }\ignorespaces #2\par
}


\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

Author:~Author \hfill Type of the work: Thesis{\parfillskip=0pt\par}

\longhang{Title}{
  Tabularx environment is not used to align long titles at the colon
  Tabularx environment is not used to align long titles at the colon
}

Date:~\today

University:~University

Department:~Department

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{oframed}
  Author:~Author \hfill Type of the work: Thesis{\parfillskip=0pt\par}

\longhang{Title}{
  Tabularx environment is not used to align long titles at the colon
  Tabularx environment is not used to align long titles at the colon
}

  Date:~\today

  University:~University of \LaTeX

  Department:~Department of Typesetting
\end{oframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this one! Do you have a modified solution for cases without parskip before but only a new line (like describe in the comment below the answer of esdd)?

Comment: @DanielStich Set `\parskip` to zero in the `oframed` environment

Comment: had to redefine it like this: `\newcommand{\FramedRule}{{\parskip=0pt\par}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}\rule[0pt]{\textwidth+2\tabcolsep}{0.4pt}{\parskip=0pt\par}\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}}`. Now everything works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion using `\@hangfrom`:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %a4paper,% default
  10pt,
  parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{framed}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{oframed}
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
  Author:~Author \hfill Type of the work: Thesis

  \makeatletter
  \@hangfrom{Title:~}{Tabularx environment is used to align long titles at the colon Tabularx environment is used to align long titles at the colon}
  \makeatother

  Date:~\today

  University:~University

  Department:~Department
\end{oframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark: Option `parskip=half` sets `\parfillskip` to `1em plus 1fil`. If the last line of a paragraph should span the whole width but
use the current settings for indentation and distance between paragraphs, then you have to change `\parfillskip` to `0pt plus 1fil` locally. Or maybe you want to use option `parskip=half-`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is neat solution. In this `oframed` environment I have defined horizontal rules like this: `\newcommand{\FramedRule}{\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}\newline\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}\rule[0pt]{\textwidth+2\tabcolsep}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-0\topsep}\newline}` and if I have a `FramedRule` and begin the next line with `\makeatletter` and `\@hangfrom`, then the rule will be shifted to the right and the alignment gets screwed up. Any idea?

Comment: `\newcommand{\FramedRule}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth+2\tabcolsep}{0.4pt}}\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}\par}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this fills your needs, because of my most recent comments, but my suggestion would be to use a `\parbox` the width of `\linegoal` from the `linegoal` package.

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    10pt,
    parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
Author: Author \hfill Type of the work: Thesis\\[\parskip]
Title: \parbox[t][2\baselineskip]{\linegoal}{This is a parbox used with the width \texttt{\textbackslash linegoal} which I am making extra long so you can see how it breaks}\\[\parskip]
Date: \today\\[\parskip]
University: University of \LaTeX\\[\parskip]
Department: Department of Typesetting\\[\parskip]

\end{document}
```

Then you can use `\\[\parskip]` everywhere (or just paragraph breaks everywhere except the first line, since the `\hfill` misbehaves then for reasons I can't figure out).

You need to compile at least twice for `\linegoal` to work right.

Output:

[image: output with linegoal]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. But now it seems like the framed environment I'm using in my main document and linegoal kind of don't like each other. Please have a look at my question edit with the new MWE for more details.